# React-Native Navigation is not visible

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-native-navigation

I've integrated my MainNavigator with all screens imported while when I ma running it on my ios simulator it shows just white screen and nothing else. It means there is not any error with running an app. I don't know why navigation is not visible.
Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator, DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';
import SigninScreen from './screens/SigninScreen';
import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import BusinessScreen from './screens/BusinessScreen';
import TechScreen from './screens/TechScreen';
import EducationScreen from './screens/EducationScreen';
import LifestyleScreen from './screens/LifestyleScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from './screens/FavoritesScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      signin: { screen: SigninScreen },
      signup: { screen: SignupScreen },
      main: {
        screen: DrawerNavigator({
          home: { screen: HomeScreen },
          business: { screen: BusinessScreen },
          tech: { screen: TechScreen },
          education: { screen: EducationScreen },
          lifestyle: { screen: LifestyleScreen },
          profile: {
            screen: StackNavigator({
              profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
              settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
            }),
          },
        }),
      },
    })
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Here are the versions that I am using in my app:

- expo 18.0.4
- react 16.0.0-alpha.12
- react-native seems the latest version at the moment. In
  package.json shows this link generated by Expo
  https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-18.0.1.tar.gz"
- react-navigation 1.0.0-beta.11

Comment: What do you mean by *"I don't know why navigation is not visible"*? What isn't visible? What do you expect to see?

Comment: I already got the solution by removing <View> tags. Navigation is not working inside <View>

Comment: @NewTechLover - After 6 hours of pain you just casually solved my issue, I owe you my first born.

Comment: @NewTechLover thanks mate, it took me so many hours to find this solution.